# BigQuery: Column name is ambiguous even after applying alias

Tags: google-bigquery

dear Stackoverflow community,

I am trying to run a query to join two datasets on one key using an alias, but the validator shows an error Query error: Column name visit_id is ambiguous

```
SELECT visit_id as a
FROM `dashboards.test.visits` FULL JOIN `dashboards.test.tracks` on visit_id;

**Schema for `dashboards.test.visits`**

Field name  Type    Mode    
visit_time  TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE    
visit_id    INTEGER NULLABLE    
device_id   INTEGER NULLABLE    
traffic_source  STRING  NULLABLE    
pages_viewed    FLOAT   NULLABLE    

**Schema `dashboards.test.tracks`**

Field name  Type    Mode    
track_time  TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE    
track_id    FLOAT   NULLABLE    
visit_id    FLOAT   NULLABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

The ambiguity is to where the column should be sourced from as it can come from both visits and tracks.  Try the following:

```
SELECT a.visit_id
FROM `dashboards.test.visits` a
FULL JOIN `dashboards.test.tracks` b
on a.visit_id = b.visit_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use USING to avoid this error

```
SELECT visit_id
FROM `dashboards.test.visits` 
FULL JOIN `dashboards.test.tracks` 
USING(visit_id);
```